# save functions when switch pages

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have these two simple functions that change the body background color

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lightson(){
    document.body.bgColor="#EBEBEB";
}
function lightsoff(){
    document.body.bgColor="#333333";
}
</script>
```

using links with onclick to exe the functions

```
<div style="color:red;">Lights: <a onclick="lightson();" href="#lOn">On</a> - <a onclick="lightsoff();" href="#lOff">Off</a></div>
```

these append the urls, but when I change them myself to `#lOff` or `#lOn` they do nothing,
how do I save what the user clicked `#lOff` or `#lOn` when they click a page on the site?

I use `<body onload="lightson();">` to set the background color on index.php, otherwise it goes to default

Answer (score 4):

To get the url part after the hashtag use

`window.location.hash`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location

You could call a function that would check the value of the hash on page load to determine which background colour to use.
I'd go for something like this.

```
window.onload = function(){
   var hash = window.location.hash;

   if(hash == "#lOn"){
      lightson();
   }else{
      lightsoff();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try some thing like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lightson(attr){
    console.log(attr); // '#lOn'
    document.body.bgColor="#EBEBEB";
}
function lightsoff(attr){
    console.log(attr); // '#lOff'
    document.body.bgColor="#333333";
}
</script>

<div style="color:red;">Lights: <a onclick="lightson('#lOn');" href="#lOn">On</a> - <a onclick="lightsoff('#lOff');" href="#lOff">Off</a></div>
```